# Traer formulario al frente si se intenta abrir por segunda vez

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy abriendo otro .exe desde mi aplicacion, pero esta se pueden minimizar y cuando intentes abrirlo nuevamente, quiero que si esta minimizada  se pase al frente y se ponga en pantalla normal con windowstate, la idea es no abrir muchas veces el mismo .exe.

tengo esto:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] namepro = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("app");
        System.Diagnostics.Process vbfrm = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process  pro in namepro)
        {
            if (pro.ProcessName != "app")
            {
                //si no esta abierto abro el ejecutable
                vbfrm.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\servidorAPP\carpeta\app.exe";
                vbfrm.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                //aqui quiero mandarlo al frente y hacer un windowstate en caso de que el proceso este abierto.
            }
        }
```

Comment: intenta con esta linea: vbfrm.BringToFront();

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que se me ocurre seria lo siguiente, (Program.cs)

```
using System.Threading;

static void Main()
{
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
bool nuevaInstancia;
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, out nuevaInstancia))
{
if (nuevaInstancia)
{
Application.Run(new Form1());
}
else
{
// LO que quieres que haga si se intenta abrir de nuevo la aplicación.
}
}
}
```

Esto no hará que se ponga `TopMost`, pero podras hacer por ejemplo que te salte un mensaje o impedir que se inicie la aplicación de nuevo.